# Finding the integral of a solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $y$ be a solution to the differential equation
>   $$(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+6y=0$$ If $y(1)=2$ find the value of the integral
>   $\int_{-1}^1y^2~dx$.

I have tried integrating the differential equation which just gives $$\int_{-1}^1\left[(1-x^2)y''-2xy'\right]dx+\int_{-1}^16y~dx\\=\int_{-1}^1\Big[\frac d{dx}(1-x^2)y'\Big]dx+\int_{-1}^16y~dx\\=\int_{-1}^16y~dx=c$$ for some constant of integration $c$. What should I do to find the value of the integral?

Comment: Yeah I am quite sure about that. But even if it wanted $\int^{-1}^1ydx$, i can only see it is equal to some constant divided by $6$, how do I get the exact value?

Comment: I know the value of $\int_{-1}^{1}y \, dx $. It is 0. Will it help you in any way?

Comment: How did you do that? Please give some hints

Comment: The regular solution to your ode, satisfying the boundary condition is $y(x)=3x^{2}-1$, thus
$$\int_{-1}^{1}y^{2}(x)dx=\frac{8}{5}$$

Comment: That is fair enough. But I tried to do it in a more elegant way, by not finding the solution at all.

Comment: I wonder if you might be able to get somewhere by starting like this: $$ \int y(y\,dx) = \overbrace{\int y\,dv = yv-\int v\, dy}^\text{integration by parts} $$

Comment: @MichaelHardy but what could be $v$?

Comment: @AbishankaSaha : I'm not sure you would need to know anything about $v$ beyond $dv/dx = y.$ But I haven't looked at this more closely than what I wrote above, so maybe you do. $\qquad$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Polynomial solution of the equation $(1-x^2)y''-2xy'+6y=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2093144/polynomial-solution-of-the-equation-1-x2y-2xy6y-0)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily recognise this differential equation as the Legendre's differential equation of order $2$. You can see [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://home.iitk.ac.in/~sghorai/TEACHING/MTH203/ode13.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjW0sDyhLzYAhUF4o8KHdoKD98QFggkMAI&usg=AOvVaw2iKvhbKw020j6Dr-ZSo07M) for reference.

---

We have the solution to the Legendre's differential equation as: $$y (x) = c_0y_1 (x) + c_2  y_2 (x)$$ with $y_1 (x), y_2 (x) $ defined as in the paper. Note that $y_1 (x)$ when $x=2$ is: $1-3x^2$. When, we define $c_0=-\frac12$, we get the Legendre polynomial $P_2 (x) $.

Generally $y_2 (x) $ is ignored. Then, do the calculations with $y = c_0y_1 (x) $.

Comment: Is it not possible to find the integral without explicitly solving the differential equation?

Comment: The solutions are actually well known. So, this is just a fact of recognising the form of the DE, then you will get the answer...